# How to preserve folder structure using file-loader with webpack, but skip "src"?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build

I'm using file-loader with Webpack 4 and I'm copying some resources as is to the `/dist` folder. It's possible by providing

`name: "[path][name].[ext]"`

as a parameter, but this results in preserving the whole folder structure (in my case, also including `src/` part). My goal is to copy the exact path of the files, but using `src/` as a root, does anybody have any experience doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack `file-loader` accepts a function for a [`name` property](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#name). You can use that to return custom computed path.

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            // name can also be a simple string if it is only path values
            name(file) {

                // generate path dynamically here
                const newPath = '[hash].[ext]';

                return newPath;
            },
        },
    }],
}
```

Also, if you really need to just copy assets from `src` to `dist`, then probably [**webpack-copy-plugin**](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) is a better way to handle it.

Comment: You don't need a function if you only use existing values like path, hash or ext, you can just do `name: "[name].[ext]"`

Comment: Copy is not always the way to go if your file will change and you want cache bust ;)